# Flex Remote Object multiple parallel calls

Tags: apache-flex, object, parallel-processing

I'm on Flash Builder 4.5 and I'm using remote object with amfphp and when I call two method (method1 and method2) at the same time the response of method2 always arrives after method1's response even though method2 is much more faster to return the result.

Here's the scenario:
I set a remote object which refers to a remote php class "Newsletter" which contains the sendNewsletter and getProgress methods.
Here's the code:

-sendNewsletter() reads the email archive and send the newsletter. After each email has sent it writes a log into the database.
-getProgress() reads the log wrote by sendNewsletter, counts how many email have been sent, compares it with the total number of the email that have to be sent and return the progress percentage

From the flex interface the users select a Newsletter to be sent and click on a "send" button which calls a function that calls the sendNewsletter() and then instantiate a loop of calls to getProgress (as you can see when getProgress returns something it calls the setProgress which updates a progress bar and calls getProgress again until the progress percentage reach 100%.

So right after I call sendNewsletter() I call getProgress() on the same remoteClass().
sendNewsletter() can take several minutes to complete (in my tests for sending 4 email it takes about 4 seconds so I think that sending thousands of email will take much more!!) and the trouble I'm encountering here is that getProgress() result arrives only after sendNewsletter() concludes its execution while what I would like to achieve is:
-call sendNewsletter()
-while sendNewsletter() does its stuff() call getProgress several time in order to get the progress percentage:

What I've got now:

call to sendNewsletter()----------------------->response
 call to getProgress()------------------------------------->response after sendNewsletter()

What I want to achieve:

sendNewsletter()------------------------------------------------------------------>response()

getProgress()--->response, getProgress() again--->response-->getProgress()-->respone-->etc...

I read many post on how to work around this problem but no solution worked for me.
I tried to to "emulate" to different channel by creating two remote object with endpoint set once to gateway.php?parallel=0 and once gateway.php?parallel=1, but flash builder still send everything in one big request and get the response in one big http packet (I need tow different packet since sendNewsletter takse ages to complete compared to getProgress)

I also tried to delay the call of getProgress() after sendNewsletter() with a Timer of 500ms and flash builder makes two different calls (I can see them in firebug) but the call of getProgress gives response after sendNewsletter() anyway.

I alse tried to call sendNewsletter this way
this.myNewsletter.getOperation("sendNewsletter").send(idNewsletter)
this.myNewsletter.getOperation("sendNewsletter").cancel()
in order to let flash builder forget about the response but no way!!!

So far the only way to work around I found is creating a common httpservice which refers to a php which instantiate the Newsletter class and calls the getProgress method.
By using two different channel I can call the getProgress httpservice while sendNewsletter is being execute. It works but I don't like it and I don't want to create an httpservice for each method I need to call in background, so I want to achieve this with remote object only.

Anyone has addressed the same problem?
You Flash builder guru, I know you're around, please help me!!!!!
Thanks in advance!!!
Bye,
Luke

P.S.
sorry if this post is a little bit long but the situation it's quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly, what you want to..

But when working with Remote Object, there is a best practices to use [Responder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/Responder.html) to handle the responses that were arrived parallel from the single Remote Object.

So try to add responder to your service calls like

```
remoteObject.methodCall().addResponder(new YourResponder(resultEvent, faultEvent));
```

So when specific response will be come, it will be handled by your different custom responders.
And by that you will be able to handle your response separately.